# Django slug without unicode

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to store my language **Title** as **URL** using Slugify.

For Eg: my **title** is *வணக்கம் நண்பர்களே* I want to store this as *வணக்கம்-நண்பர்களே* but I get *வணககம-நணபரகள* missing some elements in the words.

**Models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 55)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

**Views.py**

```
slugify(input,allow_unicode=True)
```

Comment: did you try `slugify.slugify("your text")`?

Comment: No, I'm not tried.

Comment: test it if it works

Comment: the error is coming `'function' object has no attribute 'slugify'`